# MFC CImage weird artifacts

Tags: c++, mfc, stretchblt, cimage

I am using MFCs `CDC` to try to create output and am currently trying to render some images.

In my example I want the output to be around `300x300` pixels, but the original picture is `2360x1884`. When loading this image into a `CImage` and drawing it using a `CRect` being `300x300`, the result is really crazy...

Here is the original image:

[image: Original image]

Drawn image:

[image: Printed Image]

How do I properly draw an image where the original image is larger?

Sample code:

```cpp
  CImage image;
  CDC* painter;
  CString filepath = "puppy.jpg";
  image.Load(filepath);
  CRect boundries(x, y, x + 300, y + 300);
  HDC hdc = *painter;
  image.Draw(hdc, boundries);
```

Comment: It looks to me like it has tried to turn it into palleted colour with 256 colours (and badly)? To rule out the simultaneous change in aspect ratio being an issue here try redrawing it at sizes 1180,942 and 540,471 (/2,/4). If they work OK then try 472,377 (which is not exact)

Comment: You probably are looking for this: `SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE)`

Comment: @MartinBrown I tried it with another image with original size 600x600, setting it to 300x300 causes weird color artifacts (not as bad as with the puppy, but still there).

Comment: @user20716902 I tried setting `SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE)`, did not help.

Comment: @AndréLehto, I just created a test project, I see the same color issue, and when I add `SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE);` before `image.Draw` the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `Draw` method will use the stretching Blt mode `BLACKONWHITE` which is fine if the image is the same size, however it will cause the color artifacting that you see when shrinking an image, as can be seen from the image below:

[image]

By setting the Stretch Blt Mode to `HALFTONE`, the correct color behaviour can then be observered, all that is required is to add a call to `SetStretchBltMode` before you use `Draw`:

```
SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE);
image.Draw(hdc, boundries);
```

[image]